# GoogleSignIn.requestPermissions returns a void account

Tags: google-signin

I use GoogleSignIn to access Google Photos API and manage OAuth.

Given a valid account retrieve by using startActivityForResult,
When I call GoogleSignIn.requestPermissions,
Then the previous valid account becomes void (account.object no more contains email). The returned account have the allowed permissions.

I retrieve the granted account with GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount.

```
GoogleSignIn.requestPermissions(
                    MainActivity.this,
                    RC_AUTHORIZE_PHOTOS,
                    GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(MainActivity.this),
                    new Scope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/photoslibrary.readonly"));
```

then

```
GoogleSignInAccount account = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(getApplicationContext());
```

returns an account with account.getAccount == null

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, I call requestPermissions when I call signIn. As a result, getLastSignedInAccount is always correct.

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestScopes(new Scope(Scopes.EMAIL), SCOPE_PHOTOS_READ)
            .build();
GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(activity, gso);
Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
activity.startActivityForResult(signInIntent, MainActivity.RC_SIGN_IN);
```